# MessageRead event returns empty list

Tags: python, events, event-handling, telegram, telethon

I am trying to retrieve messages that were read through MessageRead event, but when someone reads the message get_messages() returns an empty list.

Here is my code

```
#Handle read messages
@client.on(events.MessageRead)
async def handler(event):
    print('Someone has read all your messages until', event.max_id)
    s = await event.get_messages()
    print(s)
```

Could not find any solution.

[image]

I am also trying to get the content of the read message but could not find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how event.get_messages() work but I solved my problem using client.get_messages (args=event.chat_id and max_id) instead.

Comment: [`MessageRead.Event.get_messages`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/events.html#telethon.events.messageread.MessageRead.Event.get_messages) will only "Returns the list of Message which contents’ were read.". Meaning read media like voice notes. It cannot return the list of read messages, because the information isn't present (only the top `msg_id`).